# Why this is showing type error in NodeJS while using ping module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, ping

I'm trying to make a basic app to ping an IP. So my HTML form takes one input IP and post it to NodeJS.
I'm using ping module to get the results. it works fine if I enter an IP statically but when I try to get IP by HTML form it just breaks.
This is how my code looks.

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body);
   var ip= req.body.ip;
   console.log(typeof(ip));
   var msg;
   var hosts = [ip];
   hosts.forEach(function(host){
       ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
           console.log(isAlive);
           msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
           console.log(msg);
      });
  });
res.write(msg);
res.send();
});
```

[This is what comes on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7gez.png)

Comment: the error complains about the line 30 in app.js. Which line of this code snippet is line 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, this is what is happening:

1. You issue a ping request. Note, that it takes a callback function as a parameter. This suggests that this is an asynchronous I/O operation.
2. You execute

```
res.write(msg);
res.send();
```

At the time `msg` is still undefined and therefore I'm guessing that `res.write(msg)` is in fact the line 30 of app.js file that the error is all about

3. Only then the callback function is executed, but it's too late

I would recommend changing it as follows

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body);
   const ip= req.body.ip;
   console.log(typeof(ip));
   ping.sys.probe(ip, function(isAlive){
      console.log(isAlive);
      const msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
      console.log(msg);
      res.write(msg);
      res.send();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamil Janowski.
This is exactly what was happening in my code which I was able to rectify after your suggestions. It's working fine now.

Comment: i'm happy i could help. At this point it would be nice if you could either upvote my answer and/or mark it as the correct one :P only this way your question will be marked as "answered" and I'll get my reputation points :P

Comment: Sorry for that,
I'm new to the platform.